# Print archives per month

Tags: python, pelican

Is it possible to print archives on pelican per month ? like:

- Nov 2016

  - Post 4
  - Post 3
- Oct 2016

  - Post 2
  - Post 1

I know how to write jinja template, one i know to write archive is only from this file: https://github.com/getpelican/pelican/blob/master/pelican/themes/simple/templates/archives.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Archives for {{ SITENAME }}</h1>

<dl>
{% for article in dates %}
    <dt>{{ article.locale_date }}</dt>
    <dd><a href="{{ SITEURL }}/{{ article.url }}">{{ article.title }}</a></dd>
{% endfor %}
</dl>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it: http://thesoftjaguar.com/posts/2013/04/06/pelican-static-blog,

little bit modified to descending order.

```
<h1 class="page-title">Archive</h1>

<ul>
    {% for year, year_articles in articles|groupby('date.year')|sort(reverse=True) %}
    <li><h2>{{ year }}</h2></li>
    <table class="table table-condensed">
    {% for month, month_articles in year_articles|groupby('date.month')|sort(reverse=True) %}
          {% for article in month_articles|sort(attribute='date',reverse=True) %}
          <tr class="entry-archive">
            <td class="detail" width="70%">
              <a href="{{ SITEURL }}/{{ article.url }}" rel="bookmark" title="Permalink to {{ article.title|striptags }}">{{ article.title }}</a>
            </td>
              <td class="date">
                  {{ article.date.strftime('%A, %b %d') }}
              </td>
          </tr>
          {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```